# Creating multiple tables from one Table and crating unique value as primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have an EXEL file of the movies dataset and it has no primary key. I want to create multiple tables out of it and assign a primary key to each table.

Example: I want to extract the country column and make one separate table with unique countries and primary keys.

Comment: Is EXEL a typo for EXCEL and if so what does the question have to do with mysql? Have you imported to mysql into a table that you now wish to split into multiple tables? Question needs more focus..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

First import your Excel file in MySQL.

Then, update imported table structure to add an ID column with AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE `test3` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Then CREATE a new table called countries and populate it with countries found in imported table:

```
INSERT INTO countries (country) VALUES (SELECT DISTINCT(country) FROM imoprted_table;
```